# Constexpr operator new

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr, if-constexpr

Is it possible to overload the operator new to be constexpr function? Something like:

```
constexpr void * operator new( std::size_t count );
```

The reason why would be to execute constexpr function within the overloaded operator body where count argument value would be an input data... As the operator is invoked by:

```
SomeClass * foo = new SomeClass();
```

The size of the data type is know at compile time, isn’t it? (`count== sizeof(SomeClass)`) So the count can be considered as compile time constant?

```
constexpr void * operator new( std::size_t count )
{
  if constexpr ( count >= 10 ) { /* do some compile-time business */ }
}
```

Many thanks in advance to anyone willing to help!

Comment: What's the intent here of using `constexpr`? Why not a template?

Comment: constexpr cannot have side effects, thus this would be contradictory

Comment: BTW, you can have your constructor constexpr, thus I don't get the use case...

Comment: My Task is to do custom O(1) memory pool based allocation. I need to evaluate the count at compile time to select appropriate memory partition having chunks of adequate size.

Comment: The operator new can be made templated?

Comment: There is no such thing as compile-time dynamic memory allocation. Allocating memory for your program at compile time is by definition just specifying a quantity of static memory necessary at runtime. If you can calculate at compile time you need `N` bytes at runtime for your task, then just have a properly aligned `static` buffer of size `N`.

Comment: The memory chunks are made statically while the dynamic allocation itself is substituted by assigning the chunk from the memory pool...

Comment: I can't see how this would work, conceptually. Either you know at compile time what address will be returned, or you don't. The first case is compatible with `constexpr`, the second with dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: It doesn't matter anyway. [expr.const] prohibits *new-expression*s in constant expressions across the board.

Comment: You want to look at the C++2a papers trying to make everything constexpr.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Read this: http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2018/p0784r1.html

Comment: Man, these comments did *not* age well …

Answer (score 4):

You can't overload operator `new` to be `constexpr`, the main problem is attributed to the C++ standard directive *§9.1.5/1 The `constexpr` specifier [dcl.constexpr]* (**Emphasis Mine**):

> The `constexpr` specifier shall be applied only to the definition of a
>   variable or variable template or the declaration of a function or
>   function template. A function or static data member declared with the
>   `constexpr` specifier is implicitly an inline function or variable
>   (9.1.6). **If any declaration of a function or function template has a
>   `constexpr` specifier, then all its declarations shall contain the
>   `constexpr` specifier**.

That is, in order to overload operator `new` all its previous declarations must also be `constexpr`, which they aren't and thus overloading it as `constexpr` you get a compile time error.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that this is correct. Doesn't this talk about the case when there are several declarations of the same function (with the same signature)? I don't really see the rationale behind, if one overload was `constexpr`, then all of them must be `constexpr` as well.

Comment: Which version of standard has been mentioned?