# How does constexpr new allocate memory?

Tags: c++, new-operator, constexpr, c++20

How can we dynamically allocate at compile time? Does the `constexpr` `operator new` just allocate memory on the stack?

Comment: Point 22 in [this constant expression reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression) seems relevant.

Comment: related (not sure if still up-to-date) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53419133/constexpr-operator-new

Comment: please clarify, what do you mean with "the `constexpr operator new`" ?

Comment: @idclev463035818 my question was wrong, as I misunderstood the meaning of "dynamic allocations" (or, better, the use of the operator new) in a `constexpr` context. The accepted answer clarified everything

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no `constexpr new` operator.

Since C++20, you can use `new` operator in `constexpr` expressions in the condition that you only use a replaceable global allocation function (it means that you don't use a placement `new` or user-defined allocation function) and that you deallocate the data in the same expression.

So, in your final program, this does not allocate memory, since you end up just with the final result of your `constexpr` expression.

Answer (score 8):

It doesn't allocate *at all*. The compiler evaluates the result of a function that includes allocation *and* deallocation in calculating it's result.

E.g.

```
constexpr int triangle_number(int n)
{
    std::vector<int> intermediate(n + 1);
    std::iota(intermediate.begin(), intermediate.end(), 0);
    return std::accumulate(intermediate.begin(), intermediate.end(), 0);
}

std::array<int, triangle_number(5)> arr; // compiler somehow produces 15
```