# Builder patterns with vectors evaluated at compile time (with `consteval`)

Tags: c++, design-patterns, c++20, builder

I am attempting to create a class that follows the builder pattern and also runs completely at compile time (with the use of the new `consteval` keyword in C++20), but whatever I try doesn't work. For example, this won't work:

```cpp
#include <vector>

class MyClass
{
private:
    std::vector<int> data;

public:
    consteval MyClass& setData()
    {
        this->data = {20};
        return *this;
    }

    consteval std::vector<int> build()
    {
        return data;
    }
};


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> data = MyClass().setData().build();
}
```

Which gives the error "`<anonymous>` is not a constant expression". This led me to believe I should instead return copies of the class instead:

```cpp
#include <vector>

class MyClass
{
private:
    std::vector<int> data;

public:
    consteval MyClass setData()
    {
        // https://herbsutter.com/2013/04/05/complex-initialization-for-a-const-variable/
        return [&]{
            MyClass newClass;
            newClass.data = {20};
            return newClass;
        }();
    }

    consteval std::vector<int> build()
    {
        return data;
    }
};


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> data = MyClass().setData().build();
}
```

Yet, I got the same error. How should I use a constant-time builder pattern in C++? It seems this only occurs with `vector`s, and I am using a version which supports C++20 `constexpr vector`s.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code does not compile because current C++ only permits "transient" allocation in constant expressions. That means that during constant expression evaluation, it is permitted to dynamically allocate memory (since C++20) but only under the condition that any such allocations are deallocated by the time the constant expression is "over".

In your code, the expression `MyClass().setData()` must be a constant expression because it is an *immediate invocation* (which means a call to a `consteval` function, other than one that occurs inside another `consteval` function or inside an `if consteval` block). The expression `MyClass().setData().build()` also must be a constant expression. This implies that, while `MyClass().setData().build()` is being evaluated, dynamic allocations are permitted, but there must be no "surviving" allocations at the end of `MyClass().setData()` nor at the end of `MyClass().setData().build()`.

Since there is no way to prevent the result of `MyClass().setData()` from having a live allocation, you must only call it  inside an enclosing `consteval` function or `if consteval` block. For example, the following will be valid:

```
consteval int foo() {
    return MyClass().setData().build()[0];
}
```

Notice that the temporary `MyClass` object (and thus the `std::vector<int>` subobject) will be destroyed, and all dynamic allocations will therefore be cleaned up, just before `foo()` returns.

You want to keep the vector around after the outermost `consteval` function completes? Sorry, you can't do that---not in the current version of C++, at least. You need to copy its content into a `std::array` or some other kind of object that doesn't use dynamic allocation.

Comment: Then how do `constexpr std::vector`s work? I assumed that a vector could be created at compile time because of this new feature.

Comment: @AyushGarg You still cannot have a `constexpr std::vector` variable. But you can have a `std::vector` variable inside a constant expression evaluation (i.e. in a `constexpr` function). That's the new part in C++20.

Comment: @user17732522 Oh, I see... so, the heap just doesn't work. How would you suggest I copy into an `std::array`? The reason I was using `vector`s was because they're much easier to create elements in (as I am adding many more elements into the data during building).

Comment: @AyushGarg Heap does work. It is just separate from the runtime one and must be properly released before the constant evaluation ends. See for example [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72415239/how-do-i-store-the-compile-time-dynamically-allocated-memory-so-that-it-can-be-u) for how to return the vector contents as an array.

Comment: @user17732522 Sorry, that's what I meant about the heap. Thanks so much for the help! Feel free to make an answer covering how to do that, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:24:46: error: '<anonymous>' is not a constant expression
   24 |     std::vector<int> data = MyClass().setData().build();
      |                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
```

Notice how the compiler unlerlines `MyClass().setData()`.

`setData()` returns a reference to `*this`, which is of type `MyClass` and not a `const`. You actually just modified it in `setData()`. A reference to a non-const can't be a constant expression.

You can change that by returning by value: `consteval MyClass setData()`

But then you run into the problem that in a constexpr all calls to new must be balanced with calls to delete and elided. But `std::vector` calls `new` and you never destroy the vector. So you get:

> /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.1.0/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/allocator.h:182:50: error: 'MyClass::setData()()' is not a constant expression because it refers to a result of 'operator new'

You can do `consteval` if you use `std::array`. Or some other container that doesn't use the heap.

Comment: The issue with using `std::array` is that I can't add or remove elements, making it much harder to use. What do you suggest I use instead/how should I manage adding more elements? (I technically can calculate how many I need, but it can be difficult as there is a bit of math involved in figuring out how many elements to add).

Comment: Generate a vector with all the elements, then create an array of the same size, copy the elements and destroy the vector.

Comment: I didn't realize that you can use the result of `vector.size()` to use in the type of the array. Thanks!

Comment: Only in a constant evaluation context.