# Using constexpr vectors in template parameters (C++20)

Tags: c++, c++20, constexpr, template-meta-programming

Recently, I've been playing around with C++20's new `constexpr std::vector`s (I'm using GCC v12), and have run into a slight problem (this is actually an extension of [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72496216/builder-patterns-with-vectors-evaluated-at-compile-time-with-consteval), but I thought it would just be better to make a new one). I've been trying to use `constexpr std::vector`s as members to a class, but this seems like it doesn't work as you cannot annotate them with `constexpr` and therefore `constexpr` functions think they can't be evaluated at compile time, so now I am trying to use template parameters instead, like this:

```cpp
#include <array>

template<int N, std::array<int, N> arr = {1}>
class Test
{
public:
    constexpr int doSomething()
    {
        constexpr const int value = arr[0];
        return value * 100;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test<10> myTestClass;
    // return the value to prevent it from being optimized away 
    return myTestClass.doSomething();
}
```

This results in the expected assembly output (simply returning 100 from main):

```
main:
        mov     eax, 100
        ret
```

However, something like this doesn't work for `std::vector`s, *even though they can be `constexpr` now!*

```cpp
#include <vector>

template<std::vector<int> vec = {1}>
class Test
{
public:
    constexpr int doSomething()
    {
        constexpr const int value = vec[0];
        return value * 100;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test<> myTestClass;
    return myTestClass.doSomething();
}
```

This throws this error:

```
<source>:3:35: error: 'std::vector<int>' is not a valid type for a template non-type parameter because it is not structural
    3 | template<std::vector<int> vec = {1}>
      |                                   ^
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.1.0/include/c++/12.1.0/vector:64,
                 from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.1.0/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/stl_vector.h:423:11: note: base class 'std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >' is not public
  423 |     class vector : protected _Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>
      |           ^~~~~~
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:17:24: error: request for member 'doSomething' in 'myTestClass', which is of non-class type 'int'
   17 |     return myTestClass.doSomething();
```

How can I do this with `vector`s, or is it even possible? And, is it possible to make `constexpr` members, or not?

Comment: The requirements for a user-defined class to be a [non type template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters) are pretty strict. Essentially we're looking at whether they're a [literal type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/LiteralType). I think `std::array` is, but `std::vector` isn't, but I'm not sure exactly how.

Comment: Correction: C++20 doesn't just require the type to be a literal type (which it looks like `std::vector` actually is), but places further requirements on it. So the question is actually what, exactly makes `std::vector` not a structural type. Having non-public non-static data members would do it.

Comment: A `std::vector` allocated data on the heap with `new`. You can only use them in a constexpr when it gets destructed before the constant evaluation ends. So they are good as temporaries but can't be in the result. In the template type the vector would outlive the constant evaluation so to speak.

Comment: You probably can have them as static constexpr members (a non-static constexpr member doesn't make much sense anyway).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You still (in C++20 and I don't think there is any change for C++23) can't use a `std::vector` as a non-type template argument or have any `std::vector` variable marked `constexpr` or have any constant expression resulting in a `std::vector` as value at all.

The only use case that is allowed now in C++20 that wasn't allowed before is to have a (non-`constexpr`) `std::vector` variable or object which is constructed while a constant expression is evaluated and destroyed before the constant evaluation ends.

This means you can now for example take the function

```
constexpr int f() {
    std::vector<int> vec;
    vec.push_back(3);
    vec.push_back(1);
    vec.push_back(2);
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    return vec.front();
}
```

add a `constexpr` on it and use it in constant expression e.g.

```
static_assert(f() == 1);
```

But that's all. It is still very useful, because beforehand you could only use algorithms that don't need any dynamic memory allocation to calculate something at compile-time. That meant that you often couldn't just use the usual runtime algorithm/implementation directly in a compile-time context.

The same is true for any type that keeps references to dynamically allocated memory. You need to destroy them during the constant expression evaluation, i.e. they must be temporaries or local variables in a function or return values which are not stored in a runtime context.

In the specific case of non-type template arguments the situation is even stricter. Not all types that you could make a `constexpr` variable of, can be used as non-type template arguments. There are much stricter restrictions. They must be so-called *structural types*.

These are for example fundamental types such as arithmetic types, pointers, etc. A class type is a *structural type* if it is a *literal type* and also has only non-static data members which are `public` and non-`mutable` as well as all of them, recursively, *structural types* as well.

I think it is clear that `std::vector` doesn't satisfy these requirements. `std::array` is explicitly specified to be a *structural type*, which is why you are allowed to use it as non-type template argument.

Comment: So is there really no way to make a compile time builder class (with vectors) in C++?

Comment: @AyushGarg It depends on what exactly you want. If you are fine passing arguments as template arguments, then I think you can make a syntax like `std::vector<int> data = MyClass<...>().setData<...>().build<...>();` from your other question work, although maybe not so straight-forwardly. You will need to store the result in something of fixed size like a `std::array` first and then construct the vector from it. If you want to pass arguments as normal function arguments, then you can't have the type and hence the size of the intermediate depend on the actual passed values, making it harder.

Comment: @AyushGarg I would suggest you ask a question concretely about whether some small example you have in mind can be implemented. Be precise about the requirements. There will not be a general straight-forward solution.

Comment: Your example also works in C++14.

Comment: @Vegeta No, the `static_assert` will fail in C++14 because `std::vector`'s member functions are `constexpr` only since C++20. However, I made a mistake in the example and forgot to add `constexpr` on `f` (without which the `static_assert` would fail in C++20 too).

Comment: @user17732522 sorry, you're right, my project settings were still set to C++20