C++ Compile-Time Class With std::vector Member Variable and Use It's Data at Run-Time
I am trying to make a writer class, which would be used to turn data into a binary stream, at compile-time using a std::vector, and then converting it to std::array to be used at runtime. eg:
#include <cstdint>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

class Writter
{
   private:
    std::vector<uint8_t> vec;

   public:
    constexpr Writter() {}

    constexpr const std::vector<uint8_t> getVector() const { return (vec); }

    constexpr void write(uint8_t val) { vec.push_back(val); }

    constexpr size_t getVecSize() const { return (vec.size()); }
};

consteval Writter toConstant()
{
    Writter wr;

    //wr.write(1);

    return(wr);
}

consteval auto getBinary()
{
    constexpr Writter               wr = toConstant();
    constexpr std::vector<uint8_t>  vec = wr.getVector();
    constexpr size_t                vecSize = vec.size();
    std::array<uint8_t, vecSize>    arr;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < vecSize; ++i)
    {
        arr[i] = vec[i];
    }
    
    return arr;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr auto binary = getBinary();
}

The current version compiles, but as soon as you try to use the wr.write(1) member function, compilation fails with the given output:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20240725/include/c++/15.0.0/bits/allocator.h:193:52: error: 'toConstant()()' is not a constant expression because it refers to a result of 'operator new'
  193 |             return static_cast<_Tp*>(::operator new(__n));
      |                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
<source>:39:12: error: invalid types 'int[size_t {aka long unsigned int}]' for array subscript
   39 |         arr[i] = vec[i];

I have tried to use different containers, or just having a raw pointer and managing the memory myself, but the problem always seems to be that the compiler doesnt understand that the std::vector member variable (or any other container), can be evaluated at compile time.
Is there any way to make the compiler understand that it is within a constexpr context?
Edit: there are two similar question posted, but they are not quite what is being asked here, the questions and differences are;

Cannot create constexpr std::vector: this question is about the lack of support of std::vector, prior to c++20 (and the answer basically was; you need to wait for c++20).
C++20 constexpr vector and string not working: this question is about the use of std::vector and std::string, which its lifetime persist until runtime, which is not possible, because any dynamic memory allocated at runtime, has to also be de-allocated at runtime, which was not happening on OP's code.

Where as in this question, C++20 is being used, thus std::vector is supported in the context of constexpr. And the memory allocated is also free'd at compile time.
So the question rather is; How to make the data of an std::vector persist at runtime using an std::array?

wr and vec must not be constexpr variables. A std::vector can't be used as (part of) a constexpr variable. Write toConstant().getVector().size() directly to get the size as constexpr variable and don't make vec a constexpr variable at all. (toConstant() must be called twice, once for the size and once for the data. There is no way around this.)

The fundamental issue is that a constexpr variable must itself have constant initialization, regardless of the context in which it appears. And in constant evaluation of that initialization no dynamic allocation may remain allocated at the end.

possibly dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69498115/c20-constexpr-vector-and-string-not-working

Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72415239/how-do-i-store-the-compile-time-dynamically-allocated-memory-so-that-it-can-be-u

Also, consteval is probably not correct here. constexpr instead will do just fine.

See https://godbolt.org/z/n6K61jEhv for the fix I suggest.

See this answer in the dupe saying: "std::vector uses a dynamic memory allocation. Operator new can't be used in constexpr method"

Bringing the very helpful comments of user17732522 to light;
The problem lies in the fact that std::vector, even though it can be used within a constexpr context, it cannot, itself, be declared as constexpr, nor a class that contains it. (same goes for std::string and anything utilizing dynamic memory allocation)
Thus, the  toConstant() function has to be called twice, once for getting the vector (not as constexpr) and once for the size of the vector (as constexpr).
The class itself is correct, only getBinary() has to change to something like this:
consteval auto getBinary()
{
    std::vector<uint8_t>            vec = toConstant().getVector();
    constexpr size_t                vecSize = toConstant().getVector().size();
    std::array<uint8_t, vecSize>    arr;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < vecSize; ++i)
    {
        arr[i] = vec[i];
    }
    
    return arr;
}


Thanks again to user17732522, and please, if I explained something wrong, drop a comment.

The issue is that for a function to be consteval any memory allocated must be deallocated within that function. It would appear that your compiler does not allocate any memory when declaring a vector, but it clearly then must do so when you call wr.write(1). It seems that memory is not deallocated within toConstant(), perhaps because wr is moved rather than copied or perhaps for another reason. This means toConstant() is not consteval.
To make this work you can move the creation of your Writter object into getBinary(). This means the memory will be deallocated within the function in which it was allocated.
Note you must also set your vecSize to a compile time constant. My Compiler would not accept the use of std::vector::size() to provide the size for a std::array
The following function definition compiled for me.
consteval auto getBinary()
{
    Writter                         wr;
    wr.write(1);
    std::vector<uint8_t>            vec = wr.getVector();
    constexpr size_t                vecSize = 1;
    std::array<uint8_t, vecSize>    arr;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < vecSize; ++i)
    {
        arr[i] = vec[i];
    }

    return arr;
}


There is no guarantee that an empty std::vector won't allocate either. Allocation on the heap at compile-time is ok as long as it is deallocated again before the end of the constant expression. There is no problem with accessing a constexpr array at compile-time.

You were absolutely correct - I did not know the situation regarding compile time allocation and deallocation. Also, as you mentioned, my compiler would not permit even the creation of the Writter class in the toConstant() function, preumably due to some memory allocation in the std::vector. I have rewritten my answer.
